# VBA Collection bring to excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with pasting data from a collection to a worksheet.
I created a class module and populated the collection with a SQL query
the final step is to paste the data that I have in the collection in a spreadsheet, when when i run the code I receive a message of error '13' Type mismatch

```
Class Modules Company 
Public Street As String 
Public City As String 
Public Country As String 

Dim cmpCollection As Collection
Dim cmp As Company


Do While Not rs.EOF 
cmp.Street = rs!Street 
cmp.City = rs!City cmp.Country = rs!Country 
rs.MoveNext Loop 

'Where rs is a recordset with the result of the SQL query

For Each cmp In cmpCollection
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells("A1") = cmpCollection.Item(cmp)
Next cmp
```

Do you have any suggestions for that?

```
Class Modules 
Company Public Street As String 
Public City As String 
Public Country As String 
Do While Not rs.EOF cmp.Street = rs!Street
 cmp.City = rs!City cmp.Country = rs!Country rs.Move
Next Loop
```

Where rs is a recordset with the result of the SQL query

Thanks

Comment: What kind of data is in the collection? You should be using just `cmp` rather than `cmpCollection.Item(cmp)` but you need to increment the cell reference and I suspect there are better ways to do what you're doing if you're putting the result of a SQL query in a sheet.

Comment: In the collection I have three strings per each Item.

Comment: Then I suggest you post the code that actually populates the collection so we're not guessing blindly...

Comment: Class Modules Company     
Public Street As String
Public City As String
Public Country As String

 Do While Not rs.EOF
         cmp.Street = rs!Street
        cmp.City = rs!City
          cmp.Country = rs!Country 
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    Where rs is a recordset with the result of the SQL query

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is cleaner to use getters and setters in classes and use private variables. Then you can choose to only expose those properties you want to be exposed (maybe not relevant in your example, since all of them are).

Company class module:

```
'Variables stored in class:
Private p_Street as string
Private p_City as string
Private p_Country as string

'Getters to expose the stored variables to the outside world.
Public Property Get Street() as String
    Street = p_Street
End Property
Public Property Get City() as String
    City = p_City
End Property
Public Property Get Country() as String
    Country = p_Country
End Property

'Setters (Let in VBA) to populate:
Public Property Let Street(value as String)
    p_Street = value
End Property
Public Property Let City(value as String) 
    p_City = value
End Property
Public Property Let Country(value as String)
    p_Country = value
End Property
```

Now that you have your company class, you can create a collection of Company Objects in a regular module as follows (There's no need to wrap the collection itself in yet another class for now):

```
Public CompanyCollection as Collection 'Global variable, so it can be used / altered later on


Public Sub PopulateCollection()
Dim rs as ADODB.RecordSet 'I assume it's ADODB?
Dim cmp as Company
Set CompanyCollection = new Collection

'Get your recordset here

Do While rs.EOF = False
    Set cmp = New Company
    cmp.Street = rs.Fields.Item("Street")
    cmp.City = rs.Fields.Item("City")
    cmp.Country = rs.Fields.Item("Country")
    CompanyCollection.Add cmp
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Now you can loop through the Collection and write it to a number of rows in Sheet 1 as follows:

```
Sub WriteCollectionToSheet()
Dim cmp as Company
Dim i as integer 'Indexer to make sure the next row will be used for the next Company Object.

i = 1 
For each cmp in CompanyCollection 
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        .Cells(i, 1).value = cmp.Street   
        .Cells(i, 2).value = cmp.City
        .Cells(i, 3).value = cmp.Country 
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next cmp


End Sub
```

However, if you don't need this collection elsewhere, it is way more efficient to write from the RecordSet directly into the workbook.

To summarize: The above let's you transform your RecordSet into custom Company Objects that you store in a collection (through `PopulateCollection`). Since the CompanyCollection is stored as a global variable, you can later on access it and write the items stored in it to a worksheet using `WriteCollectionToSheet`.

However, depending on the scenario, I would advise against this all together and just populate the cells directly from the recordset, or, if there is a default unparameterized query, just use Excel's native Connections and simply execute `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`